# Using existing answer as a hint text

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, text, textfield

i'm trying to display the existing answers that are stored in the list   `List<Data> data = [];` as a hint text if they're available. currently i'm using this [code](https://pastecode.io/s/bj9jkx06): https://pastecode.io/s/bj9jkx06

the error is that if i answer the question number two, the hint text will show in the textfield number one.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Data object is not required.
I would simply use another map<String, String> where the key is the question, exactly as your others maps.

```
Map<String, String> data = {}
```

This requires the data loading inside the read method to be changed as follows:

```
raw.forEach((key, value) {
   data[key] = value;
});
```

Now that your data are loaded, you can retrive the hint for the question in this way, using the question as the key:

```
String hint = data[question] != null? data[question] : 'write something';
```

If data doesn't contains record related to a specific question, it will return 'write something' string

Comment: thank you, this's exactly what i wanted

Comment: another question, everytime i submit a texfield, it overrides the map. so it'll only save the new answers, is there a way to overpass this/. like if the texfield is empty. but there is already an answer saved, the map doesn't erase it and saves the new answers only

Comment: If you want to avoid the map value to be overwritten, you could add a check when you submit the answers.
Someting like this: data[question] = answer != '' ? answer : data[question].

If you want to maintain an history of answers, that's a whole other question and it would require a different structure for your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the **TextField** on the **InputDecoration** property of hintText it takes a string like

```
hintText: "Hint Text"
```

Comment: i'm doing that, `hintText: hint` and:
`String hint = data.length <= index ? 'write something' : data.elementAt(index).answer`

Comment: check the code above, i'm trying to show the existing answers as the hint text

Comment: data[index].answer not data.elementAt(index).answer try this

Comment: with square bracket [ ]

Comment: this doesn't work at all, u cant use square brackets for .elementAt function . even trying `data[index].answer` doesn't solve the problem

Comment: you are in a Stateful Widget try to set state to the hint variable what do you think about that

Comment: already tried that too, not working.

Comment: Why are you checking if the data length is less than the index? Won't that mean for answer 1, it must be less than 1 character, for answer 2, it must be less than 2 characters, and so on?

Comment: not sure that i understand ur comment. but that's the only way that line of code worked. i was checking if the data length is less or equal to the current index then show the data.answer in that index. if not show "write something"

Answer (score 0):

just to remind you, `index starts with 0`. So you are getting one `textfield` behind.